# Xamarin.iOS Mask Layer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

i want to cut out a quarter circle from an image. I do it with UIBezirPath and the CAshapeLAyer.
But it doesn work
This is my code

```cs
UIBezierPath path = new UIBezierPath();
nfloat startAngle = 0;
nfloat endAngle = 90;
nfloat radius = (float) (size.Height/2);
CGPoint center = new CGPoint(size.Width /2, size.Height / 2);

path.MoveTo(center);
path.AddArc(center,radius,startAngle,endAngle,true);
path.AddLineTo(center);
path.ClosePath();
CAShapeLayer maskLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
CGRect cgRect = new CGRect(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
maskLayer.Frame = imageHolder.Bounds;
maskLayer.Path = path.CGPath;
maskLayer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Brown.CGColor;
maskLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Cyan.CGColor;
imageHolder.Layer.Mask = maskLayer;
imageHolder.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
imageHolder.ClipsToBounds = true;
```

I dont't know why it doesn't work. 
It show only the original ImageView.

Comment: define "doesn't work".  Does it do NOTHING?  Or does it do something, but not what you want?  Does it crash or give an error message?

Comment: The App is running, but i see the original Image. No snippet from the Image.